# Designer editor is unavailable Android studio

Tags: android

When I was trying to open Android studio for the first time to start my project.
It was showing design editor is unavailable.

It was showing some errors

these are the errors showing:
[image: these are the errors showing]

The errors in the compiler are shown in the image:
[image: The errors in the compiler are shown in the image]

Tell me what is wrong with the project. I am a beginner in Android programming

Comment: Can you write your whole path of the newCurrency.png ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per android guidelines you have to give name of image in small letter

For Example in your case you have image name like, "newCurrency.png"

Please change it into "new_currency.png"

and check this will be working.